# Copy cell text from E and F on Book1 over to Book2 if a string match is found in column A?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'll try to explain this as concisely as I can, and please interject if something doesn't make sense.

So I have an inventory spreadsheet (call it Book1) of server data that I generate every month, but there are a few columns that get updated manually (E,H,I,J,K) because the this information changes. What I need to do is copy over that updated info to the next newly generated spreadsheet (call it Book2) at the end of the month if the hostnames in column A find each other (servers are created and deleted all the time).

I have some VBA that works perfect, but only for columns E and F. I'm hopeful that someone can edit it to copy over E,H,I,J,K.

```
Sub test()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range, fn As Range
Set sh1 = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Set sh2 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Sheets(1)
    For Each c In sh1.Range("A2", sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        Set fn = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(c.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
            If Not fn Is Nothing Then
                If fn.Offset(, 4).Value <> c.Offset(, 4).Value Or fn.Offset(, 5).Value <> c.Offset(, 5).Value Then
                    c.Offset(, 4).Resize(, 2).Copy fn.Offset(, 4)
                End If
            End If
        Set fn = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Old September inventory:

[image]

New October inventory:

[image]

Thank you!

Greg

Comment: If VBA is allowed you should add the tag to get a little more exposure.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the advice, will add VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add `c.Offset(, 7).Resize(, 4).Copy fn.Offset(, 7)` to your existing code?

```
Sub test()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range, fn As Range
Set sh1 = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Set sh2 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Sheets(1)
    For Each c In sh1.Range("A2", sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        Set fn = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(c.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
            If Not fn Is Nothing Then
                c.Offset(, 4).Resize(, 2).Copy fn.Offset(, 4)
                c.Offset(, 7).Resize(, 4).Copy fn.Offset(, 7)
            End If
        Set fn = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This works!.. but it's only copying over 10% of everything it should?

Comment: Only 10% of the rows, columns or cells? The code still only compares columns E and F to determine if it should act. If either column E **or** column F don't match, it replaces all six cells of that row.

Comment: Copying should only occur if for example the text in old spreadsheet A2 match up with new spreadsheet A2, if they do then copy over E2,H2,I2,J2,K2 from old spreadsheet to new spreadsheet.

Comment: After finding a match in Cell A2, your existing code further checks that E **or** F in `sh2` contain different values than `sh1` and only then copies the values. I've edited my answer to remove this additional, conditional statement. This will perform unnecessary copy/pastes, but it should fill in the remaining 90%.

Comment: That's the ticket! Thank you!! I've marked you as the answer, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

`c.Offset(, 4).Resize(, 2).Copy fn.Offset(, 4)`

with

```
sh1.Range("E" & c.Row).Copy sh2.Range("E" & fn.Row) 'E
sh1.Range("H" & c.Row & ":K" & c.Row).Copy sh2.Range("H" & fn.Row & "K" & fn.Row) 'because H,I,J,K are adyacent, we can do it in 1 line code
```